# Replace single and double quotes with QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, convert, query, filter

I have a dataset containing special characters `'` and `"`. I want to replace them with nothing. I tried to replace them with the `replace` function but it shows some error. Is there any other expression to replace these characters?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use regular expressions with [`regex_replace()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace) function. The single quote `'` has to be masked by a backslash: `\'`. Use this expression to get rid of single `'` and double quotes `"`:

```
regexp_replace (Dataset, '(\')|(")', '')
```

---

To also replace backslashes `\`, you must mask them with additional backslashes: `\\\\`:

```
regexp_replace (Dataset, '(\')|(")|(\\\\)', '')
```

With the `or` operator `|` you can add as many additional characters to delete as you want. Put the character to be replaced in brackets `()` .

[image]

Answer (score 8):

you can use this expression:

```
replace(replace("fieldname", char(34), ''), char(39), '')
```

char(34) corresponds to the double quote `"`

char(39) corresponds to the simple quote  `'`

Comment: is anything for '\'

Comment: `char(92)` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters